# Android AAPT2 link fails with "conflicting values"

Tags: android, aapt2

i'm trying to build an Android app referencing the androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13 package, and unfortunately the AAPT2 link phase always fails for me with these three errors:

```
values.xml, line 4 — aapt2 link: resource 'color/primary_text_default_material_dark' has a conflicting value for configuration ().
values.xml, line 5 — aapt2 link: resource 'color/secondary_text_default_material_dark' has a conflicting value for configuration ().
values.xml, line 7 — aapt2 link: resource 'integer/cancel_button_image_alpha' has a conflicting value for configuration ().
```

these values are indeed duplicated, from resources in `appcompat-1.4.1` and `media-1.5.0`

I'm not referencing either of these directly, but `legacy-support-v13` pulls in `appcompat-1.4.1`, and that one in turn pulls in `media-1.5.0`, si i am assuming these two packages are *supposed* to be ab le to co-exist.

What could i be missing here?

ps: i am using my own build chain, cunning `aapt2 compile` and `aapt2 link` manually...

thanx!